# expected number of edges in a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

If we have a random graph $G \in g(n,\frac{1}{2})$ how do we show that the expected number of edges is $\frac{1}{2} {{n}\choose{2}}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the model in which for every (unordered( pair $\{u,v\}$ of vertices we decide independently, with probability $1/2$, whether or not there is an edge joining $u$ and $v$? Then it should not be hard, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{I}_k$ be the indicator function for the edge $k$, i.e.,
$$\mathbb{I}_k = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if $k^{th}$ edge is present}\\ 0 & \text{ if $k^{th}$ edge is not present} \end{cases}$$
The quantity you are interested in is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}2} \mathbb{I}_k\right) & = \sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}2} \mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{I}_k\right) \left(\because \text{By linearity of expectation} \right)\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}2} \mathbb{P}\left(\mathbb{I}_k=1\right) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}2} \mathbb{P}\left(\text{$k^{th}$ edge is present}\right)\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\binom{n}2} \dfrac12 \left(\text{Assuming that it is equally likely for an edge to be present or absent} \right)\\
& = \dfrac12 \dbinom{n}2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You have $^nC_2$ edges with probability of connecting = $\frac{1}{2}$. So the result.